# Match zero or one specific character anywhere in a word

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to find a regular expression that will satisfy this rule:

*The word can contain any English alphabetical character, apostrophes and a single hyphen, but double hyphens will not be accepted.*

So these are fine:

```
o'clock
brother-in-law
```

But this isn't:

```
stack--overflow
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
^[a-zA-Z\']*\-?$
```

It will work if the hyphens are at the end of the string but obviously not anywhere in the string as I need.

Thanks in advance,
Luke

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use a single regular expression to make sure the string contains letters, apostrophes and single hyphens? It would be simpler and much faster to ensure the presence of these characters first, then test if there are consecutive hyphens.

Comment: @Jerry: I would prefer to, just so the code is a little cleaner, what is making you advise against it? Performance?

Comment: Performance and readability. Reability because... well would you be able to tell what the regex proposed below actually do if they were not explained? What about the next person who will take you place (in a business context), will they be able to modify the code should there be a higher restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use a simple regex without any lookaheads:

```
^[A-Za-z']+(?:[-'][A-Za-z]+)*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pX9mD1/3)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - Start of string
- `[A-Za-z']+` - 1 or more English letters or a `'`
- `(?:[-'][A-Za-z]+)*` - A non-capturing group that matches 0 or more occurrences of

  - `[-']` - a hyphen or an apostrophe
  - `[A-Za-z]+` -  1 or more English letters
- `$` - End of string

**Update**:

In case there can be both `'` and `-` at the beginning and the "word" can end with a hyphen, you can use:

```
^-?[A-Za-z']+(?:-['A-Za-z]+)*-?$
```

**Explanation**:

- `^` - Start of string
- `-?` - Optional hyphen
- `[A-Za-z']+` - 1 or more letters or apostrophes
- `(?:-['A-Za-z]+)*` - a non-capturing group that matches 0 or more times sequences of

  - `-` - hyphen
  - `['A-Za-z]+` - 1 or more apostrophes or letters
- `-?` - Optional hyphen at the...
- `$` - end of string.

With a case-ignoring option `/i`, you can also shorten it to

```
/^-?[a-z']+(?:-['a-z]+)*-?$/i
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/pX9mD1/9)

Comment: After your edit, this works fine too, thank you very much :)

Comment: Yes, I see, sometimes, it is better to overmatch than undermatch.

Comment: @Jonny5: Now, I made it work without look-arounds. Whenever there is a way without them, I prefer that way.

Comment: What is the advantage @stribizhev? Speed? Simplicity? I need it to match rock''roll by the way

Comment: @LukeBenting: Yes, performance. Since you say consecutive apostrophes are allowed,  I guess  you can then try [`^-?[A-Za-z']+(?:-['A-Za-z]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/pX9mD1/7). Or, if your "word" can end with a hyphen, you can try [`^-?[A-Za-z']+(?:-['A-Za-z]+)*-?$`](https://regex101.com/r/pX9mD1/8).

Comment: Just checked: Avinash's regex [does not match `rock''roll`](https://regex101.com/r/yP8xO6/1) and needs ~6 times more steps to complete on the same string as mine.

Comment: I've tested it many times and Avinash's regex does match rock''roll, atleast in the environment I'm working on and on regexr.com. If you update your answer with the latest regex that you commented with, I will accept yours as the answer :)

Comment: I updated the answer. Are you working in JavaScript then?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this,

```
^(?!.*--)[A-Za-z'-]+$
```

But this allows `''` if you don't like this then use the below.

```
^(?!.*(?:--|''))[A-Za-z'-]+$
```

Comment: [`-stack-overflow-`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!.*--)%5bA-Za-z%27-%5d%2b%24&i=-stack-overflow-) will also get matched. Is it OK?

Comment: if you don't want to allow hypen at the start `^(?!.*(?:--|'')|-)[A-Za-z'-]+$`

Comment: I think that is actually fine @stribizhev, but thanks for the additional answer Avinash